# Problem with integrating DiracDelta

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

I thought I had found a bug in Mathematica and reported it already in version 9, since it wasn't fixed in version 10 or 11 I reported it two more times but I never get any reply whatsoever so I'm thinking perhaps it is not a bug and I have just misunderstood the way Mathematica is supposed to work.

I do not expect these last two integrals to give 0 but they do. Should they not return 1? The first two integrals return what I expect them to and are just provided for comparison.

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[Cos[θ]] θ, {θ, 0, π}]
Integrate[DiracDelta[Cos[θ]] Exp[θ], {θ, 0, π}]
Integrate[DiracDelta[Cos[θ]] Sin[θ], {θ, 0, π}]
Integrate[DiracDelta[Cos[θ]] UnitStep[θ], {θ, 0, π}]
```

Comment: Please do not use `Bugs` tag for initial posts, it is intended to be used *after* confirmation by participants.

Comment: Fort the last example, `Integrate[
 DiracDelta[Cos[\[Theta]]] UnitStep[\[Theta]] // 
  Simplify[#, 0 <= \[Theta] <= \[Pi]] &, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}]` evaluates to `1`

Comment: For distributions, it is better to use `HeavisideTheta` instead of `UnitStep`, since `HeavisideTheta` is a generalized function (distribution) and `UnitStep` is not. `Integrate[DiracDelta[Cos[t]] HeavisideTheta[t], {t, 0, Pi}]` does return 1. This is covered in the documentation in the tutorial on GeneralizedFunctions.

Comment: All the integrals under consideration make no sense (see https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Delta-function and https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Generalized_function as a first reading for explanation).

Comment: @user64494 Why do they not make sense to you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd consider it a bug.

Reason: I would consider following identity:
$$\delta(f(x))=\sum_i\frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|f'(x_i)|}$$

Where $\forall x_i : f(x_i)=0$

This leads us to:
$$\delta(\cos x)=\frac{\delta(x-\pi/2)}{|-\sin(\pi/2)|}=\delta(x-\pi/2)$$

So we conclude:
$$\int_0^\pi\text{d}x\;\delta(x-\pi/2)\cdot\sin x=\sin(\pi/2)=1$$
The same for [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep.html). And Mathematica realizes this:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[x - Pi/2]*Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]
Integrate[DiracDelta[x - Pi/2]*UnitStep[x], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

> 1
>
> 1

With FullSimplify before:

```
FullSimplify[DiracDelta[x - Pi/2]*Sin[x], 0 < x < Pi]
FullSimplify[DiracDelta[x - Pi/2]*UnitStep[x], 0 < x < Pi]
```

> 2 DiracDelta[[Pi] - 2 x]
>
> 2 DiracDelta[[Pi] - 2 x]

Which evaluates in Integrate to:

```
Integrate[2 DiracDelta[\[Pi] - 2 x], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

> 1

So, my vote is on bug.

Answer (score 14):

I also vote for a bug. The easiest way to see it is using an undefined function,

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[Cos[x]] f[x], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

which gives `f[Pi/2]`. So for an undefined function it gives the right answer but for `f=Sin` it **does not** give `Sin[Pi/2]`. Hence a Bug.