# How to prove that relation with DiracDelta in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Up to Encyclopedia of Mathematics (see example 7 [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Generalized_function)), the relation
$$\delta(\sin x)=\sum\limits_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} \delta(x-k\pi)$$
is valid.

Trying to verify it in Mathematica,
I obtain

```
DiracDelta[Sin[x]] === DiracComb[Pi*x]
```

> False

Also (making use of nonstandard Mathematica notation) the command

```
Resolve[ForAll[x, DiracDelta[Sin[x]] == DiracComb[Pi*x]], Reals]
```

fails.

Comment: I would also very much like to teach mathematica to know about such things !

Comment: First of all, `===` is not the correct thing to use because that checks to see if the *expressions* are *structurally* identical, not mathematically equal. Secondly, `InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[DiracDelta[Sin[x]], x, k], k,
  x]` seems to disagree with your statement.

Comment: @march: Can you base your statement? I'd like to quote the documentation "lhs===rhs
yields True if the expression lhs is identical to rhs, and yields False otherwise ".

Comment: Expressions being "identical" is not the same as them being mathematically equivalent. Example: `Sin[2 x] === 2 Sin[x] Cos[x]`; the `Head` of the lhs is `Sin` and the `Head` of the rhs is `Times`, which are not identical.

Comment: @Michael E2: Many thanks from me to you for your explanation. The documentation to === is too poor. In particular, "identical" is not defined at all. BTW, (2 + 3)^2 === 25 performs True whereas (x + y)^2 === x^2 + 2*x*y + y^2 performs False.

Comment: @user64494: It most certainly defines it in the documentation: "... Here, "identical" means there is exact correspondence between the underlying FullForm representations of expressions Subscript[expr, 1] and Subscript[expr, 2]..."

Comment: @ciao: Thank you. What's the difference between  (2 + 3)^2 === 4 + 2*2*3 + 9 which performs True and (x + y)^2 === x^2 + 2*x*y + y^2 which produces False? TIA.

Comment: Both sides of `===` are evaluated.  Some expressions automatically evaluate to others such as `(2+3)^2` --> `5^2` --> `25` and some do not such as `Sin[2 x]`. If the results are identical, you get `True`. You can prevent evaluation with `Hold[(2 + 3)^2] === Hold[4 + 2*2*3 + 9]`. You can observe the user-level steps of evaluation with `Trace[(2 + 3)^2 === 4 + 2*2*3 + 9]`.

Comment: @Michael E2:" Some expressions automatically evaluate to others such as (2+3)^2 --> 5^2 --> 25 and some do not such as Sin[2 x]". All that is over my understanding.

Answer (score 5):

Due to the [bug reported here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136214/29734), the following method actually gets the wrong answer. However, the *method* is a good one for proving the relation in the OP.

---

One way to check is to take advantage of the fact that *Mathematica*'s symbolic Fourier transform functionality can deal with these things.  Note:

```
FourierTransform[DiracDelta[Sin[x]], x, k]
(* DiracComb[k]/Sqrt[2 π] *)
```

and

```
InverseFourierTransform[DiracComb[k]/Sqrt[2 π], k, x]
(* DiracComb[x/(2 π)]/(2 π) *)
```

which illustrate the fact that `DiracDelta[Sin[x]]` and `DiracComb[x/(2 π)]/(2 π)` are the same. Evidently,
$$
\delta(\sin(x)) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\left(\frac{x}{2\pi}-n\right),
$$
according to the definition of `DiracComb` in the documentation. This then simplifies to
$$
\delta(\sin(x)) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\left(x-2\pi n\right).
$$

Comment: @user64494 This doesn't agree with the page that you linked. Using the Fejer kernel to numerically approximate the delta function, it seems like the relation in your question is correct. In that case, *Mathematica* is wrong. For further evidence, [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136214/problem-with-integrating-diracdelta?rq=1) is relevant. This is likely a bug in *Mathematica* that is still around in V12. However, if *Mathematica* didn't have this bug, the method I've outlined is one way to prove the relation, so I'll leave it as is.

Comment: Thank you for your interest to the question and your work. However, the actions of FourierTransform and InverseFourierTransform on DiracDelta related functions are not reliable and correct in many cases. Here is an example: FourierTransform[t^2*DiracDelta[t - 1], t, s] $$\frac{e^{i s}}{\sqrt{2 \pi }} $$  InverseFourierTransform[%, s, t] $$\delta (t-1) $$ In view of it I do not appreciate your answer.

Comment: You produce $$  \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\left(x-2\pi n\right)$$ instead of $$  \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\left(x-\pi n\right).$$

Comment: My final comment to your answer. I think your statement "
Due to the bug reported here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136214/problem-with-integrating-diracdelta , the following method actually gets the wrong answer" does not correspond to reality. The Fourier transforms of generalized functions are a subtle matter (see https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fourier_transform_of_a_generalized_function as a first reading).