# Problem with the Fourier transform of |sin(x)|

Tags: fourier-analysis

The code `FourierTransform[Abs[Sin[t]], t, w]` gives me a timeout like *"This computation has exceeded the time limit for your plan."*

What indeed *is* the FT of $|\sin(x)|$ ? Why can't Mathematica compute it ?

Comment: The Fourier transform of $|\sin t|$ does not exist in traditional math because the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |\sin t|\,dt$ diverges (see https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fourier_transform for info).

Comment: @user64494 $|\sin t|$ is tempered so its Fourier transform is perfectly well-defined. This is explained in your own link ("*In classical analysis such a generalization has been constructed for locally integrable functions...*"). Please stop making wrong statements about distributions, or learn the basics first.

Comment: Pulling an actual book from my shelves, I find that Bracewell has the transform of `Abs[Cos[t]]` in his "pictorial dictionary". Adjusting for his eccentric scaling, it's the same as the series in the answers below, but with signs of terms alternating to get the phasing right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Abs` isn't analytic, and using it here seems to lead `FourierTransform` to get lost in the complex plane. Use `RealAbs`:

```
FourierTransform[RealAbs[Sin[t]], t, w]
```

yielding:

[image]

Since the function is periodic, its transform is a train of delta functions. Something like `FourierSeries` might be more illuminating here. Maybe something like:

```
ComplexExpand[FourierSeries[RealAbs[Sin[t]], t, 10]]
```

yielding:

[image]

is what you want.

Comment: thanks for the answer! could I get further insight by perhaps getting the magnitude of this complex result? ```Abs[%]``` does not seem to work because of the infinite sum.

Comment: The result of FourierTransform[RealAbs[Sin[t]], t, w] is [CASE:4370384] reported by me on 08.01.20 This result is not a closed-form expression, but an  analytic expression (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression ). It is difficult to work with it. I was answered that the Mathematica  devolopers were informed about that.

Comment: @user64494 : what closed-form do you expect for an infinite train of delta functions?

Comment: I think the command FourierTransform[RealAbs[Sin[t]], t, w] should fail (i.e.the input should be returned).

Comment: @user64494 : but it gives something that appears to be a correct answer. What's wrong with that?

Comment: 1. The Fourier transform of $|\sin t|$ does not exist in traditional sense (see my comment to the question). 2. The series $$\sum _{K[1]=-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} (-1)^{K[1]+1} \left((-1)^{K[1]}+1\right) \left(1+i^{K[1]}\right)^2 \delta (2 w+K[1])}{K[1]^2-4}  $$ is not grounded. I find it in  neither Wiki nor Encyclopedia of Mathematics. Also think of the cases $K[1]=2$ and $K[1]=-2$, where the denominator equals zero. Hope I am clear. However, don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @user64494: it exists in the pragmatic sense that we use in applied physics, and my `FourierSeries` result along with @mikado's `DiracComb` result are perhaps better representations.

Comment: I'd like to recall that the theory of distributions was developed because "the pragmatic sense that we use in applied physics" leads to wrong results in many cases. BTW, have you read about the cases $K[1]=2$ and $K[1]=-2$ in my above comment? I prefer arguments over emotional words.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104443/discussion-between-john-doty-and-user64494).

Answer (score 8):

You can obtain a simple expression using the convolution theorem.  A single cycle of the waveform is given by

```
sig = Sin[t] UnitBox[t/π - 1/2]
```

This has a relatively simple Fourier Transform

```
spec = FullSimplify[FourierTransform[sig, t, ω]]
(* -((1 + E^(I π ω))/(Sqrt[2 π] (-1 + ω^2))) *)
```

We can convert our single cycle into a periodic signal by convolution with a Dirac Comb.  This transforms to another Dirac comb

```
combspec = FourierTransform[DiracComb[t/π], t, ω]
(* Sqrt[π/2] DiracComb[ω/2] *)
```

By the convolution theorem (this probably needs multiply by a something like `2π`), the Fourier transform of periodic signal is given by

```
Assuming[ω/2 ∈ Integers, FullSimplify[combspec*spec]]
(* DiracComb[ω/2]/(1 - ω^2) *)
```

Note that we can simplify the factor in front of the comb, as its value only needs to be correct for cases where the comb is non-zero.

Comment: However, the actions of FourierTransform and InverseFourierTransform on DiracDelta related functions are not reliable and correct in many cases  (see that recent discussion https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212352/how-to-prove-that-relation-with-diracdelta-in-mathematica/212354#212354 ) .

Comment: With this excellent answer, we now have three different approaches yielding equivalent results.